# Minecraft: Why does my opened to LAN world not show up in my other laptop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

I am really annoyed of this problem. I have did everything that everyone said, like run the **Command Prompt** and find the specific IP *(they matched)*, **restart** Minecraft, **uninstall** all other Java versions unnecessary, I have turned off **Firewall**, and other stuff, but it **STILL** does not show up. I am on a wired connection *(I use a normal computer with a CPU on it, obviously)* and my cousin is using a wireless connection. We **ARE** on the same connection, just the difference of having wired and wireless. Does that difference affect the problem I'm having now?

And to all the other people, I know this *might* be a duplicate, as other people have asked similar questions, but I tried the answers people gave to them, and those still do not fix the problem.

Comment: All the extra bold and italics makes your question much harder to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you checked that the ports are open on the router? I would search for your router type and how to open ports on it. AS it does not matter if your PC firewall is off if the router is not opening the ports for others on your network. You could also do a direct connect if that does not work. You will need to get your network IP for your computer and then direct connect to it

Comment: Open ports on the router are not relevant to this issue - opening means enabling access from outside network. Machines on the same LAN network should be visible to each other, unless broadcast packets are somehow blocked by the router.